# jsSocials share to Pinterest image_url error

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm using [jsSocials](http://js-socials.com/) to add some nice-looking sharing options to a site. It mostly works well, but the pinterest sharing button always ends with an error on pinterest:

> Parameter 'image_url' (value http:null) is not a valid URL format.

I'm using some pretty vanilla code from their examples:

```js
jQuery(".socialnetworkwrap").jsSocials({
 showCount: true,
 showLabel: true,
 shares: ["email", "twitter", "facebook", "googleplus", "linkedin", "pinterest"]
});
```

This works fine, but in an attempt to fix this issue, I've tried the following from [their documentation](http://js-socials.com/docs/).  I've also verified that the imageToShare object is returning a valid value through an alert.

```js
var imageToShare = jQuery('div.content p img:first').attr('src');

jsSocials.shares.pinterest = {
 media: imageToShare
};

jQuery(".socialnetworkwrap").jsSocials({
 showCount: true,
 showLabel: true,
 shares: ["email", "twitter", "facebook", "googleplus", "linkedin", "pinterest"]
});
```

When I do this though, I get an error on my site.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined

Does anyone have experience with this plugin?  What do you suggest to attempt to fix this pinterest error?

Answer (score 3):

Ugh... I didn't find this until I saw it on the GitHub version of the documentation...

This sets the default image just fine and allows Pinterest sharing to work.

```js
var imageToShare = jQuery('div.content p img:first').attr('src');

jsSocials.setDefaults("pinterest", {
 media: imageToShare
});

jQuery(".socialnetworkwrap").jsSocials({
 showCount: true,
 showLabel: true,
 shares: ["email", "twitter", "facebook", "googleplus", "linkedin", "pinterest"]
});
```